# Bed leveling compensation not working!

Tags: heated-bed, diy-3d-printer, z-axis, troubleshooting, bed-leveling

I have a DIY 3D printer that uses a probe as z min limit and bilinear bed leveling. The problem is that bed leveling compensation sometimes doesn't work.

This is in my starting scripts in Simplify3d:

```
M106 S200
G28
G29
```

Upon printing, it turns the fan on, home all axes and bed leveling is done perfectly but **sometimes** when I start printing, Z-axis compensation doesn't work. It's random, often when I restart my PC it fixes the problem.

Comment: You don't have much information for us to work with, unless you can replicate the problem that it is not occurring sometimes, it is really difficult to answer the question. Can you somehow troubleshoot the problem to find under what circumstance this happens? Also, printing from PC to printer is not recommended, when your PC crashes or shuts down, your print will fail. SD-printing or use of a dedicated printer server (Raspberry Pi with OctoPrint) is much more safe.

Comment: What kind of printer design in general are you using? do you have a Z-limit switch or do you use a probe to ge Z? Do you possibly use mesh bed leveling?

Comment: I use Arduino Mega+Rams 1.4 combination... my printer looks a lot like prusa i3 printers. I use a probe for min z axis and bi-linear bed leveling.